# Failed audit - Can I get a second opinion please?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

I just failed an audit by marking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189587/carousel-in-controller-is-messing-with-sizes-in-my-collection-view-objective-c) as: *Off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")...

Can I get a second opinion please?

To me the question doesn't meet SO standards.  My rational for closing were:

- Hard to read explanation
- No code
- Confusing images/mockups
- Context may be too specific to be useful for other readers

I do understand that this is not a completely terrible question so if my interpretation/standard was wrong and the consensus is that the question is good, that's fine, I will accept that and learn from my mistakes.

Comment: It had a bounty, which increased the vote count on the last day. I don't know enough about ios to judge it technically, but it *looks* like a better question than most of the new ones that come in with that tag; so probably wasn't dv & closed as quickly as, say, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406492/i-am-not-able-to-use-ttf-fonts-in-my-project) should be.

Comment: @gnat Thanks for that dupe link.  I am familiar with that flakiness of the review system but just wanted someone else to confirm my opinions on the question before I went ahead and did anything outside the review queue.

Comment: @TZHX  I probably shouldn't be surprised by the effect the bounty has on the upvotes.  I do agree that the question is not terrible, but just because it's in a tag that gets a lot of crap questions shouldn't be a reason to let it slide through if it's not up to scratch.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it should be a reason to let it slide, just suggesting it as an explanation for how it managed to.

Comment: @TZHX Cool, fair point.

Comment: I agree on 2 of your 4 points, and I would had flag with the same reason (nearly impossible to help without the code used, it would be guessing only). I don't find the explanation so hard to read, separators between images would help to spot the problem, for the context I'm not and IOS dev so can't judge. Main problem is the lack of code but maybe for IOs devs it is not needed (but I think it is). My 2cts.